# Touch-to-zoom animation in Codename One

Tags: codenameone

I have an image inside a Codename One `Label`. I would like to open it to fullscreen after a tap and with an animation zoom, like in this video:
https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/android/docs/training/animation/anim_zoom.mp4

How can I get something similar using Codename One? Thank you for any hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do two things:

- Place the image in a layered layout on the entire form and just `animateLayout()` the UI. This will produce this effect without moving to a new form. Assuming the image is a `ScaleImageLabel`.
- You can move to a separate `Form` with a transition that mutates the content of the current form in that way specifically `MorphTransition` which was designed just for this effect. Make sure to use `setName` for the component in the source and destination forms so the transition will know which component to morph into which. You can morph multiple components:

  ```
  MorphTransition m = MorphTransition.create(1200).morph(componentName);
  ```